# Difference between isomorphisms, deformations, diffeomorphisms and homeomorphis,s

Tags: algebraic-geometry, soft-question, complex-geometry, deformation-theory, birational-geometry

I am learning about complex algebraic varieties and have encountered several equivalence relations: isomorphism, birational, deformation equivalent, diffeomorphic and homeomorphic. I consider all of these equivalence relations with respect to the analytic topology (but I only consider algebraic varieties).

First question: Are there any other equivalence relations worth knowing?

What are the correct implications? Of course "isomorphic" implies "everything". "Diffeomorphic" implies "homeomorphic", but what is the relation between "deformation equivalent" and "diffeomorphic" for instance?

What are some standard examples and where can I read about them?

I would like to emphasize that I am learning about smooth projective varieties over the complex numbers. But certainly these notions also appear in the study of real manifolds, right?

Note. Varieties X and Y are deformation equivalent if there is a connected space T and a family of varieties over T such that X and Y arise as fibres of this family. I also want this family to be algebraic in general.

Comment: All of the relations you list are examples of isomorphisms in a particular category. Category theory generalizes this notion of equivalence that you're asking about. Also, homeomorphic implies deformation equivalent, so diffeomorphic does too.

Comment: Does homeomorphic really imply deformation equivalent? I thought there were examples of non-deformation equivalent algebraic surfaces with the same Chern classes and Kodaira dimension.

Comment: No, homeomorphic does not imply deformation equivalent, but it does imply homotopy equivalent.

Comment: Presumably homeomorphic means with respect to the analytic topology?

Comment: Yes. I should have said that.

Comment: I believe that the first comment here is not quite right: deformation equivalent implies diffeomorphic (e.g. by the Ehresmann for smooth complex families), but the converse need not be true. Deformation equivalent doesn't imply homeomorphic either, since one can take a flat family of (complex) cubic curves degenerating to a cuspidal curve.

Comment: For a proof of the first fact: there is a 2007 paper of Catanese-Wajnyrb producing complex algebraic surfaces which are pairwise diffeomorphic but not deformation equivalent: http://archive.ymsc.tsinghua.edu.cn/pacm_download/21/677-JDG-76-2-177-213.pdf